# Common lookup table and entity relationship questions

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Second year CS student here.

Questions:

1. Is the 'Results' Table currently creating a 'common look-up table'?
2. How do I solve Employment-student relationship?

Database problem:

For each student they would like to know which degree program they were on (a student may have studies for more than one degree but not at the same time); the modules they took and their final results. For their employment they would like to know the type of employment (Full Time or Part Time, Permanent or Fixed Term, Continued Education, Taking gap year); their job title and whether it is considered a ‘Graduate’ role; The name and address of the employer; a contact email for the student, whether we can use that information for publicity purposes and a brief description of their role.

My current design for Database:

[Current ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTO2B.png)

Q1.

I noticed when constructing the ERD there was a ternary relationship between Module, Degree and Student and decided to solve this many to many problem by creating a fourth table called results. It has foreign keys from Module, Degree and Student and contains the Result date and Result score for a student in a module on a degree. Considering each student takes several modules there will be a lot of entries, will 'Results' form a common look up table? I heard these were not best practise when constructing a DB. This design also makes it difficult to query which degrees each student has done (each student can take many degrees just not at the same time). I considered creating separate tables for the Student-Module relationship and Student-Degree relationship however you then would not know which module was taken under which degree.

Q2.

I was given this advice by my lecturer:

The relationship between employment and students it not quite clear and would require some explanation. Typically an employment in the real world is between 1 employer and 1 employee only, not multiple employees per employment.

[Student-Employment Relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AfJC.png)

Is this a suitable fix? I currently have a foreign key in student which relates to their employment. Am i still able to use this or am i thinking about this relationship all wrong?

The database should support the following queries:

1. For a particular student their employment details
2. Details of students for which they do not have Employment records
3. Details of students who were unintentionally unemployed within 6 months of their graduation
4. % of students employed within one year of graduating according to class of degree
5. % of students in a graduate role for a particular year and degree program

All answers are greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: First, "common lookup table" isn't a formal term, I suggest you disregard the concept. Second, your diagram isn't an ERD, more of a table diagram. For an ERD, use Chen's notation or something equivalent. Lastly, a student may be employed multiple times, sometimes even by the same employer.